# Best way to get all subsites

Tags: performance, spweb, spsitedataquery

I want to create a list of all subsites (all levels), and some details about each of them.
The simplest way is to do a recursive function, but I have many subsite (about 600) and I want a more efficient way.

Is SPSiteDataQuery may be appropriate in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used SPSiteDataQuery, but I have used PowerShell to return a list of all subsites from a SharePoint Web Application (it returns the title, url, and id of each) and saves it to a CSV file: 
 Get-SPWebApplication "http://webappname/" | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, URL, ID | Export-CSV C:\IterateAllSitesSubsites.ps1.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: It works. Do you know if there is corresponding code in C#?

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637872/sharepoint-c-sharp-retrieve-all-site-and-subsite) which explains how to find this information using C#. Also, this article from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462161.aspx) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I researched a way to do this before.  In my case I needed to get a list of all sites across all site collections and even between multiple farms.  I ended up creating my own timer job that ran every hour to update a database where I stored the structure.  Also, every evening I ran another timer job to store in a different table who has access to read what site.  That way I can easily create a "my team sites" webpart which quickly displays all of the sites a user has access to.  With this setup and some column indexing I was able to get my webpart to run in under 2 seconds and sometimes displaying thousands of team sites.

Comment: It's a good idea, but does not exactly fit my needs. Thanks anyway.